# Preventing apply from returning a vector?

Tags: r, apply

I'm running a large number of data frames with variable dimensions through a series of apply() calls that look something like the code below.

```
df1 = t(data.frame('test'=c(0,0,1,0)))
df1 = apply(df1,2,function(j){sub(0,'00',j)})
df1 = apply(df1,2,function(j){sub(1,'01',j)})
df1 = apply(df1,2,function(j){sub(2,'10',j)})
df1
```

In some rare cases where the data frame is size 1xn the first apply() call will cause it to return a vector data type and causing an error with subsequent applys. Note this problem does not appear to occur with 1xn data frames (in the above code, remove the t()). Is there any quick/clean way to prevent apply() from returning vectors or other efficient workarounds for this issue?

I think the following might work when 1xn but no nx1 data-frames are used as input.

```
df1 = apply(df1,1,function(j){sub(0,'00',j)})
df1 = apply(df1,2,function(j){sub(1,'01',j)})
df1 = apply(df1,2,function(j){sub(2,'10',j)})
t(ret)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what data types you're referring to? None of the objects in your example are data frames. `t()` converts to a matrix, and `apply()` always converts data frames to matrices first (and in fact that's why you should almost never use it on data frames). Do you mean that you have a lot of matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following preserves the original data structure. Is it what's looked for?

```
df = data.frame('test'=c(0,0,1,0))
df[] <- apply(df,2,function(j){sub(0,'00',j)})
df[] <- apply(df,2,function(j){sub(1,'01',j)})
df[] <- apply(df,2,function(j){sub(2,'10',j)})
df
#   test
# 1   00
# 2   00
# 3   01
# 4   00

df1 = t(data.frame('test'=c(0,0,1,0)))
df1[] <- apply(df1,2,function(j){sub(0,'00',j)})
df1[] <- apply(df1,2,function(j){sub(1,'01',j)})
df1[] <- apply(df1,2,function(j){sub(2,'10',j)})
df1
# [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# test "00" "00" "01" "00"
```